# c# register form mysql insert

Tags: c#, mysql, insert

So im having problem gettin some data in to the database.. Im really stuck, im quite new to c# and have not learned all keywords yet, im not getting any errors just some nothing adds to my database.

```
        textBox2.Text = myPWD;
        MySqlConnection conn = new MySqlConnection("test")

        string Query = "INSERT INTO `users`.`coffekeys` (`koffekeys`) VALUES ('values = @val')";
        MySqlCommand data = new MySqlCommand(Query, conn);
        MySqlDataReader myReader;

            conn.Open();
            SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", this.textBox2.Text);
            conn.Closed()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Manipulate the concatenation of value in passing of parameters. Don't do it inside sql statement.

```
string Query = "INSERT INTO `users`.`coffekeys` (`koffekeys`) VALUES (@val)";
// other codes
SelectCommand.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", "values = " + this.textBox2.Text);
```

the reason why the parameter is not working is because it was surrounded by single quotes. Parameters are identifiers and not string literals.

The next problem is you did not call `ExecuteNonQuery()` which will execute the command.

Before closing the connection, call `ExecuteNonQuery()`

```
// other codes
data.ExecuteNonQuery();
conn.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks!  so i just have to execute the executenonquery befor connclose?

Answer (score 1):

You should Google around and you will receive lots of content
You need to run ExecuteNonQuery

```
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constring);
con.Open();

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(
    "insert into st (ID,Name) values ('11','seed');", con);

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
cmd.Close();
```

Comment: Thanks, althought im using mysql

Comment: This is the error im getting, what can be wrong?

Incorrect integer value: 'volum = @val' for column 'koffekeys' at row 1


            conn.Open();
            data.Parameters.AddWithValue("@val", this.textBox2.Text);
            data.ExecuteNonQuery();
            conn.Close();

Comment: As it says "Incorrect integer value:", check datatype in mysql and value you are inserting from textbbox

Comment: Everything is set, it generates a 4 number code and it should take that code and input it on the database

Comment: This type of error comes when complete circle is not drawn, so you will need to check datatype and value.
If you are trying to insert string in int datatype it will give this error.

Comment: Check this 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43438/Connect-C-to-MySQL

This is a detailed description about mySql stuff, I feel this will sort all your issues.

Comment: Ok, i updated the code. i still have sql error this is my query

CREATE TABLE `users`.`coffekeys` CHANGE COLUMN `koffekeys` `koffekeys` INT(4) NOT NULL  ;